# Trying to get property of non-object, variable is an XML statement, in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to assign a value from an XML file to a variable in nested for loops. The value does output correctly in the html file, but it still gives "Trying to get property of non-object" for each of the lines each time it goes through the code.

My code:

```
$drName=(string)$xml->Device[$lDev]->Drives->Drive[$n]->Name;
$drBadSect=(string)$xml->Device[$lDev]->Drives->Drive[$n]->BadSectors;
$drPwrHrs=(string)$xml->Device[$lDev]->Drives->Drive[$n]->PowerOnHours;
$drPwrCycle=(string)$xml->Device[$lDev]->Drives->Drive[$n]->PowerCycleCount;
$drTemp=(string)$xml->Device[$lDev]->Drives->Drive[$n]->Temperature;
$drError=(string)$xml->Device[$lDev]->Drives->Drive[$n]->Error;
```

This particuliar part of the XML file:

```
<Drives total="1">
    <Drive> 
    <Name>sda</Name>
    <BadSectors>0</BadSectors>
    <PowerOnHours>3869</PowerOnHours>
    <PowerCycleCount>10</PowerCycleCount>
    <Temperature>0</Temperature>
    <Error>0</Error>
</Drive>
```

I don't see what I am missing, and I even tried a line like:

```
$drName=(string)$xml[Device[$lDev]][Drives][Drive[$n]][Name];
```

but like that I ended up with a parse error, unexpected [ expected ]

What other option do I have except change the alert level for the php intrepeter?

Comment: Show us your whole code, including the loop. What is `Device[$lDev]`, for instance?

Comment: SimpleXML will throw notices if an element was not in the XML (and did not converted into an object/property). I you are not sure that an element is always there, you have to check for it before reading.

Comment: The whole file is kind of large (about 150 lines), so there is a [link here](http://www.nodetx.com/node-scripts/datto2dbSQL.zip).
$lDev is a looping variable going through the xml file. Device[] is the array of devices I am monitoring.